# How to debug "This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way." when I can't even step in the code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, debugging, crash, visual-studio-debugging

I have a C++ program that is giving this error as soon as the process starts - apparently before any user code executes. It only happens when inlining is enabled. Even with debug symbols built in, I can't step in the code. As soon as I press F10 in Visual Studio I get the error and the program stops. I checked all exceptions/checks in "Debug/Exceptions" but still don't get a break.

Normally I would expect something like this to be due to a missing runtime dependency but I'm quite positive that's not the case here (verified with Dependency Walker).

edit: I used Steve Townsend's recommendation of CDB and now I'm able to step through the pre-user-code parts of the program. The final stack trace is:

```
Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00000000`0008e308 00000000`7541601a ntdll!ZwTerminateProcess+0xa
00000000`0008e310 00000000`7540cf87 wow64!Wow64EmulateAtlThunk+0x86ba
00000000`0008e340 00000000`7539276d wow64!Wow64SystemServiceEx+0xd7
00000000`0008ec00 00000000`7540d07e wow64cpu!TurboDispatchJumpAddressEnd+0x24
00000000`0008ecc0 00000000`7540c549 wow64!Wow64SystemServiceEx+0x1ce
00000000`0008ed10 00000000`7776ae27 wow64!Wow64LdrpInitialize+0x429
00000000`0008f260 00000000`777672f8 ntdll!LdrGetKnownDllSectionHandle+0x1a7
00000000`0008f760 00000000`77752ace ntdll!RtlInitCodePageTable+0xe8
00000000`0008f7d0 00000000`00000000 ntdll!LdrInitializeThunk+0xe
```

Comment: Is there anything in the output window?

Comment: You should still be able to attach a debugger and look at the callstack.

Comment: Any external (non-Windows) libraries being used? I had this problem and it was being caused by one of my external libs (from LabView). I had to delay-load it.

Comment: `Even with debug symbols built in, I can't step in the code.` Do you mean before `main()` executes? Just a guess here...Well Global variables are created before main execution begins so maybe something is wrong in there...

Comment: @Mark Ingram: No.
@AJG85: Apparently not!
@RedX: A bunch of my own libraries, but those are used by other executables that are working fine, which leads me to believe that it's something in the application code (which is just a single file; it's a command-line app).
@AIs: Is there any way to dig into those?

Comment: @Matt Chambers: just put break points in construtors of classes which create global objects.

Comment: I narrowed it down to some of my code that causes a .NET dependency. But another application that has the same dependency works fine. :/ I'm going to try a debug build with inlining turned on.

Comment: @Matt do you use these libs in the same combination in your other applications? My problem only arised when i tried to combine the LabView Dll with a TwinCAT DLL. Both work fine if separated but together caused problems.

Comment: @Redx: In this case, the libraries are all statically linked. The other applications that work use the same libraries, but fewer features from them.

Comment: The debug build with inlining turned on didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try setting up [Process Dumper](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=4060) and configure it for your EXE to create a dump on any process exit.  Then start the process from the command line to rule out any artifacts of the IDE.

This ought to give you a dump for post-mortem debugging, and maybe a callstack fromm the exiting thread that could be useful.

Comment: Ah, I think you led me to the right rabbit hole. It seems UserDump (User Mode Process Dumper) is only applicable for Windows 2003 and earlier. For Vista and 7 (I'm on Windows 7 64-bit), google suggests adplus. But then I read this:
**You should not use ADPlus in the following situations: If you have to troubleshoot an application or process that ends unexpectedly during startup. You can use ADPlus only together with processes that start successfully. If you have to troubleshoot processes that end unexpectedly during startup, you should use CDB, WinDbg, or UserDump instead.**

Comment: Hope that helps. I was originally going to suggest WinDbg but was not sure it would hook the process any earlier than the IDE. CDB is probably the best bet, lack of GUI is not going to be a big hindrance given the simple and early repro.

Comment: Now at least I'm able to see some steps before the crash! But I have no idea what it means. :( See the updated question.

Comment: I set this as the "answer" even though I didn't really come close using this approach to solving my problem. :( I ended up refactoring some code to remove a library dependency (one of my own libraries, which worked fine with the other executables in my suite) and the problem stopped happening. I'll probably run into it again later...

Comment: @Matt - not certain that you will run into the problem again.  As noted in @Adrian's answer, this could be to do with order of init in global vars so shuffling the pack or removing a dependency could fix this.  Glad you are rolling again, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It probably has to do with the order that your globals are being initialized.  In C++, the order between modules is unspecified.  So if a global's initializer depends on a global in another module already being initialized, you're in trouble.

It's possible to put a break point in the CRT initialization code that runs before calling main (or wmain, or WinMain, or whatever you're using).  You can step through that code and see what's causing the problem.

Another possible cause is a DllMain function is returning an error or throwing an exception during DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH.

Comment: All of my globals are primitives or don't have any dependencies. I'm well aware of the static initialization order problem. I use a boost.vault singleton class for my globals with dependencies. But that's instantiated on demand, not before main. And this particular application that's crashing doesn't add any globals (singleton or otherwise) at all, so why would it crash when its sibling apps using the same libraries don't?